# ActiveRecord validation statement containing ||

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, conditional-statements

I've done some searching online, and understand how ActiveRecord validations can be built with "if" statements and separately defined methods. However, I'm wondering if it's possibly to simply combine two validations together, and if either is true, the whole thing passes.

What I'm trying to do is have a user input a contact field that can either be an email or a phone number, but not both. Obviously the code I have below isn't working, but I'm wondering if something similar to it could work?

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
VALID_PHONE = /\d{10}/

validates :contact, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX } || presence: true, length: { is: 10 }, format: { with: VALID_PHONE }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to recommend using a standard `:if` option for the validates callback, but having done a little more research, I found something you may benefit from:

---

[**Custom Validations**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)

According to the Rails guide:

```
#app/models/concerns/my_validator.rb
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless record.name.starts_with? 'X'
      record.errors[:name] << 'Need a name starting with X please!'
    end
  end
end

#app/models/person.rb
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

This allows you to create your own validation method, allowing you to append error messages directly into the instance variable (which is then shown on the form). For your question, I'd to do this:

```
#app/models/concerns/phone_email_validator.rb
class PhoneEmailValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    contact = record.contact
    phone = /\d{10}/
    email = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

    if contact.validate(phone) || contact.validate(email)

        if contact.validate(phone) && contact.length < 10
           error = "Length too short for phone number!"
        end

    else
      error = 'Needs To Be Phone Or Email '
    end
    record.errors[:contact] << error
  end
end

#app/models/person.rb
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

The function is too verbose, and might not work with the validation regex; but it's an idea either way!

Comment: Thank you this is a really good idea! I saw the custom methods that could be made but didn't think to use it in this way.